# I can't send controller errors to view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

with I manage to print in the index view of the delivery notes directory what was sent by the controller, something was wrong when sending the return.

**Return Controller**

```
 return view('albaranes/index',['errors','NOOOOO']);
```

**Data collection on the blade**

```
@if ($errors->any())

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>

@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

try `withErrors()`

you need to retrun back with error

```php
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['errors' => 'NOOOOO']);
```

---

or if you want to pass in as data then

```php
return view('albaranes/index')->with(['errors','NOOOOO']);
```

in blade

```php
@if ($errors)

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
      {{ $errors }} // as it is not array as u mention 
    </ul>
</div>

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are setting the array wrongly, try this way:

```
return view('albaranes/index',['errors' =>'NOOOOO']);
```

even like this, `$errors` will be a string, not an array, you could try:

```
return view('albaranes/index',['errors'=>['error1', 'error2']]);
```

You'll have to replace the `any()` and `all()` methods for methods for arrays , like this:

```
@if (count($errors)>0)

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>

@endif
```

and that should do it, I tried and it prints the list.

Comment: When using your code in controller the error that I get is the following: Call to a member function any() on array

Comment: It still does not work, but may it be that being already on the index view delivery albaranes it does not work well?

Comment: the thing is, I don't need to reload the page so I have plenty of return view, sorry for the bad explanation

Comment: okay, I found it, just suppress `all()`, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should try this maybe it will be helpful for you

```
$errors = ['You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.'];

return view('albaranes/index',compact('errors'));
```

then in blade file

```
@if (count($errors))

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>

@endif
```